# How to use BeautifulSoup after using Selenium to navigate to page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have successfully used selenium to click through a few pages on a website, and now I need BeautifulSoup to parse the data. The problem is that for some reason bs4 thinks that I am on the previous page, so none of my `find_all` calls are working. Below is a snippet of my code. The `calendar_search.click()` call is working to load the desired page. I do an exaggerated implicit wait to let the page load. Per previous SO Q&As, I set the `html` and `soup` variables below. I throw in another implicit wait for good measure. When I call `prettify` I can see that I am printing html from the page I was on prior to `calendar_search.click()`. How do I load the current page? Thank you.

```
calendar_search.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(30)

html = browser.page_source
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Edit: I tried an explicit wait (see below) and the exception printed, despite the 1000 seconds! Edit2: Part of the page must have loaded because I got x[0] of a find_all list I made. I'm having trouble reproducing the results, however.

```
try:
    element =  WebDriverWait(browser, 
    1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
    'classname')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Comment: Can you let us know the url?

Comment: I'm not sure of my ground here but let me offer the following. When you do `driver.get` `selenium` waits on `load` before returning. It might do the same thing for a `submit`. Then, assuming that your `click` is in a form you could instead use a `submit` which would make `selenium` wait. **I don't know** why this would make any difference. I'd still like to see the url.

Comment: This is on the southwest airlines page. I'm on the page that comes after the page where you click "Flexible Dates" and you can see the entire month. The exact url is `https://www.southwest.com/flight/shortcut/select-flight.html?fromShowItinerary=1&int=`

Comment: Wow, thank you and no worries if you can't. Here is how to get there: (1) go to https://www.southwest.com/flight/, enter the two cities, and click "Search." (2) Click the "Flexible Dates" box that has a little "Search Now" sub-box. This should lead you to the page I am trying to parse. This page shows a calendar with prices for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some strange reason using `browser.implicitly_wait()` doesn't work but `time.sleep()` works well. I just changed the `browser.implicitly_wait(30)` to `time.sleep(30)` and it worked perfectly. 
I've used chrome driver. Don't forget to put the chrome driver in the working directory to avoid `driver not found` error.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.southwest.com/flight/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

departure = browser.find_element_by_id("originAirport_displayed")
destination = browser.find_element_by_id("destinationAirport_displayed")

departure.send_keys("Chicago (Midway), IL - MDW")
destination.send_keys("New Orleans, LA - MSY")

button = browser.find_element_by_id("submitButton")
button.click()

time.sleep(30)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

browser.save_screenshot(browser.title + ".JPEG")

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

**EDIT**
`lxml` parser is faster than `html` parser. In the official [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) of `BeautifulSoup` they recommend to use `lxml` parser.

Comment: So `browser.implicitly_wait()` didn't work for either of us. Appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. In the end, I chose different classes for the items I was parsing (using `find_all`). The `try` and `except` statements seem critical for the program to work because different parts of the page appear to load at different times. That may be the major takeaway. I'm still not sure why certain classes seem not to load even with 1000 seconds passed in to the wait statements.